# How to validate a date Pattern in an Angular project

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So I have been learning how to use Validations in Angular to check for a pattern or if a Field is empty or some minimum length ext.... I have found many interesting Stuff on the net how to do this, but its not working for me. In my University they wrote it like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemService } from '../item.service';
import { ItemPriority, TodoItem } from '../todoitem';

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-items',
  templateUrl: './items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./items.component.css']
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {

  items: TodoItem[];
  selectedItem: TodoItem;

  addItemForm: FormGroup;

  dateRegEx: RegExp;
  
  readonly datePattern: string = "([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[-](19|20)\d\d$"
  readonly prioPattern: string = "^(Low|Medium|High|Urgent)$"

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
      this.addItemForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
      description: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(20)]],
      deadline: [null, [Validators.required]],
      priority: [null, [Validators.required]]
    });

    this.dateRegEx = RegExp(this.datePattern);
  }
```

When you read it, its very unclear how we verify the deadline pattern. I think Validators.required only check if the field is empty or not but somehow when i run my Angular project, if i write for example 13/02/2020 its wrong because there isn't a 13. Month.
On the net, I have another form more understandable. Something like this

```
  export class ReactiveFormComponent implements OnInit {
  unamePattern = "^[a-z0-9_-]{8,15}$";
  pwdPattern = "^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{6,12}$";
  mobnumPattern = "^((\\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$"; 
  emailPattern = "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$";
  
  isValidFormSubmitted = null;
  
  userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.unamePattern)]],
    password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pwdPattern)]],
    mobileNumber: ['', Validators.pattern(this.mobnumPattern)],
    email: ['', Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern)],
  });
```

But somehow its not working. Do check if needed the whole project. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GUEDv8ZDkCC_NX1y6fD-_H5NNpPqARXi/view?usp=sharing
Thank you !

Comment: hello, it would be better if you re-produce your project with [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).. By the way i did not understand if your problem is with the date validator patterns? or with all patterns ?

Comment: My problem is with the date Validator. It works but I don't know why. If it helps I'll do it now. My question is how does it work ? What part of code says, if you don't find the right format, show the error ?    deadline: [null, [Validators.required]], checks only if its empty, why does it check the format correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after analysing your project code, i found that using **matDatePicker** will automatically trigger an in-built date format validator called **matDatePickerParse** which will try to parse date and trigger an error if this is an invalid date by returning error object containing both **matDatePickerParse** and **required** errors keys.

Here is how i analysed the validator :

```
constructor(private itemService: ItemService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    ...
    ...
    this.addItemForm.valueChanges.subscribe(dt => {
      console.log(this.addItemForm.get('deadline').errors); <=== 
    })
  }
```

and here is the result of my test :
[image]

also you can check [MatDatePicker documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) for more informations.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah i've seen it now.